# Predicate logic, path length with $2$ variables

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

We have a graph as a structure and $2$ constants in our signature, $\tau = (E^2, s^0, t^0)$.

I have to create a formula for every even $k$ such that there is a path with length $k$ from $s$ to $t$, the formula shouldn't have more than $2$ variables.

---

I guess it would already help a lot to get a formula for $k = 4$, then I can try to generalize it myself. The only thing I have so far is $∃a∃b∃c(¬a = b ∧ ¬a = c ∧ ¬b = c ∧ E(s, a) ∧ E(a, b)∧ E(b, c) ∧ E(c,t))$, this has $3$ variables and doesn't seem useful at all. I don't even know if I'm supposed to use the constants that way. I guess an idea could be to look at a vertex and check if it has an incoming and outgoing edge and then you go to a different vertex and check if it's connected with the other vertex and so on. But I don't know how to do that. And then you could perhaps do something with cardinality ∃a∃b∃c(¬a = b ∧ ¬a = c ∧ ¬b = c ∧ ∀x(x = a ∨ x = b ∨ x = c)), not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: Am I correct to interpret the assignment as "Let $k$ be any positive even integer.  Write a formula, containing at most two variables, which is satisfied if and only if the graph structure has a path with length $k$ from $s$ to $t$."?

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to write a single formula for every $k$, I'd guess it's good enough to find it for $4$ and $6$, there's probably a pattern.

Comment: I suspect that if the solution is not basically what @MichaelWeiss has given, this is impossible.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question by editing to replace it with an entirely different question. Instead, just ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the trick is that you can reuse the variables. According to the usual rules of the predicate calculus, if an occurrence of a variable is bound by an "inner" quantifier, then an "outer" quantifier doesn't bind it---the occurrence is "invisible" to the outer quantifier.

Using this, here's a formula insuring a path from $s$ to $t$ of length *at most* 4.

$$\exists x(E(s,x)\wedge\exists y(E(x,y)\wedge\exists x(E(y,x)\wedge\exists y(y,t))))$$

As for *exactly* length 4: well, the above guarantees a path of length 4, just not without repeated nodes and edges. If that's also a requirement, then I'm out of ideas.

Of course, reusing variables like this is a bad idea from a readability standpoint.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! I thought about it a lot and I also couldn't find something for exactly $4$.

Comment: Check the definition of “path” being used.  The most common definition allows repetitions, which contribute to the path length. So this would count as “exactly 4”.